# Dynamically reload a class definition in Python

Tags: python, reflection, twisted

I've written an IRC bot using Twisted and now I've gotten to the point where I want to be able to dynamically reload functionality.

In my main program, I do `from bots.google import GoogleBot` and I've looked at how to use `reload` to reload *modules*, but I still can't figure out how to do dynamic re-importing of classes.

So, given a Python *class*, how do I dynamically reload the class definition?

Comment: Are you attempting at self modifying code? Why otherwise dynamically REload a module? At any rate, the problem is that once instantiated, even if the class module is reloaded the instance will not be changed and will continue to run the old code. If you reload a class code, you must create a sort of copy constructor in the class and create a clone of the instance with the new functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, here's the code I use:

```
def reimport_class(self, cls):
    """
    Reload and reimport class "cls".  Return the new definition of the class.
    """

    # Get the fully qualified name of the class.
    from twisted.python import reflect
    full_path = reflect.qual(cls)

    # Naively parse the module name and class name.
    # Can be done much better...
    match = re.match(r'(.*)\.([^\.]+)', full_path)
    module_name = match.group(1)
    class_name = match.group(2)

    # This is where the good stuff happens.
    mod = __import__(module_name, fromlist=[class_name])
    reload(mod)

    # The (reloaded definition of the) class itself is returned.
    return getattr(mod, class_name)
```

Answer (score 2):

Reload is unreliable and has many corner cases where it may fail. It is suitable for reloading simple, self-contained, scripts. If you want to dynamically reload your code without restart consider using forkloop instead:

http://opensourcehacker.com/2011/11/08/sauna-reload-the-most-awesomely-named-python-package-ever/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reload the module using `reload(module)` when using the `from X import Y` form.  You'd have to do something like `reload(sys.modules['module'])` in that case.

This might not necessarily be the *best* way to do what you want, but it works!

```
import bots.google

class BotClass(irc.IRCClient):
    def __init__(self):
        global plugins
        plugins = [bots.google.GoogleBot()]

    def privmsg(self, user, channel, msg):
        global plugins
        parts = msg.split(' ')
        trigger = parts[0]
        if trigger == '!reload':
            reload(bots.google)
            plugins = [bots.google.GoogleBot()] 
            print "Successfully reloaded plugins"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do a `from ... import ...` it binds the object into the local namespace, so all you need to is re-import it.  However, since the module is already loaded, it will just re-import the same version of the class so you would need to reload the module too.  So this should do it:

```
from bots.google import GoogleBot
...
# do stuff
...
reload(bots.google)
from bots.google import GoogleBot
```

If for some reason you don't know the module name you can get it from GoogleBot.**module**.

Comment: This is exactly what I want to achieve, but I need to do it programmatically, given only the class.

Answer (score 0):

Better yet subprocess the plugins, then hypervise the subprocess, when the files change reload the plugins process.

Edit: cleaned up.

Comment: That's something you usually do not want to do with an IRC bot since it will then quit and rejoin all channels, probably resulting in some time where it reacts only sluggishly due to throttling on the ircd side.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd really like to figure out how to do it "my way" as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sys.modules` to dynamically reload modules based on user-input.

Say that you have a folder with multiple plugins such as:

```
module/
  cmdtest.py
  urltitle.py
  ...
```

You can use `sys.modules` in this way to load/reload modules based on userinput:

```
import sys

if sys.modules['module.' + userinput]:
    reload(sys.modules['module.' + userinput])

else: 
    ' Module not loaded. Cannot reload '
    try:
        module = __import__("module." + userinput)
        module = sys.modules["module." + userinput]
    except:
        ' error when trying to load %s ' % userinput
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def reload_class(class_obj):
    module_name = class_obj.__module__
    module = sys.modules[module_name]
    pycfile = module.__file__
    modulepath = string.replace(pycfile, ".pyc", ".py")
    code=open(modulepath, 'rU').read()
    compile(code, module_name, "exec")
    module = reload(module)
    return getattr(module,class_obj.__name__)
```

There is a lot of error checking you can do on this, if your using global variables you will probably have to figure out what happens then.