# Can I alter Python source code while executing?

Tags: python-3.x, runtime

What I mean by this is:

I have a program. The end user is currently using it. I submit a new piece of source code and expect it to run as if it were always there?

I can't find an answer that specifically answers the point.

I'd like to be able to say, "extend" or add new features (rather than fix something that's already there on the fly) to the program without requiring a termination of the program (eg. Restart or exit).

Comment: You might be able to get away with it if you forced a re-import of everything. Python caches imports, which is when it creates those `.pyc` files that you see. Forcing a re-import of everything in your `main` could potentially do what you want

Comment: so basically reload(foo); import foo?

Comment: I would think so. But I like @randomusername's answer better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can definitely do that in python.

Although, it opens a security hole, so be very careful.

You can easily do this by setting up a "loader" class that can collect the source code you want it to use and then call the `exec` builtin function, just pass some python source code in and it will be evaluated.

Comment: Since my question basically needed a boolean answer... how I do it however is going to be interesting. A few suggestions from all users and some other questions have given me a few ideas of where to start. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check the package

http://opensourcehacker.com/2011/11/08/sauna-reload-the-most-awesomely-named-python-package-ever/ . It allows to overcome certain raw edges of plain exec. Also it may be worth to check [Dynamically reload a class definition in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9645388/dynamically-reload-a-class-definition-in-python)